# Video resolution to show full screen video in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, video, avplayer

I want to show a video while app is launching,
but video gravity is set as aspectfit to scaled video.
So video shows some empty space in some devices.

But as per client, video should be edge to edge in all devices, 
Can anyone let me know the proper dimension of video which its in all devices?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

Well you will have to fit it to your Screen with AutoLayout

https://theswiftdev.com/2017/10/31/ios-auto-layout-tutorial-programmatically/

Or you will have to do it programmatically by setting it to the size of your UIViewController with:

```
view.bounds.width
view.bounds.height
```

Or to the Screensize with:

```
UIScreen.main.bounds.width
UIScreen.main.bounds.height
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, but I think you misunderstand my question... I need to know the video resolution size in portrait mode which its in all device.